# SQL Stored Procedure with While loop and results inserted into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, stored-procedures, while-loop

I am trying to create a dynamic stored procedure with a loop that inserts data into a temp table in SQL Server 2008.

So far i have this code but not sure if the logic is correct with the creating table and i am not sure where to put the insert part of the query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NominalRecord]
@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6),
@CurrentPeriod INT,
@ENDPeriod INT, 
@Nominal INT

AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @ENDPeriod = @CurrentPeriod-5

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempResults')IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempResults

WHILE (@CurrentPeriod<> @ENDPeriod)--loop through until endperiod is reached

    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #TempResults(ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, CostCode INT, CostDescr VARCHAR(50), BankACType CHAR(2), FinPeriodNr SMALLINT, 
                BalJan DECIMAL(12, 2), BalFeb DECIMAL(12, 2), BalMar DECIMAL(12, 2),
                BalApr DECIMAL(12, 2), BalMay DECIMAL(12, 2), BalJun DECIMAL(12, 2),
                BalJul DECIMAL(12, 2), BalAug DECIMAL(12, 2), BalSep DECIMAL(12, 2),
                BalOct DECIMAL(12, 2), BalNov DECIMAL(12, 2), BalDec DECIMAL(12, 2), Balance DECIMAL(12, 2))


    SET @SQL = N'SELECT CostCodes.CostCode, CostCodes.CostDescr, CostCodes.BankACType, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.FinPeriodNr, 
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJan, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalFeb, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMar,
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalApr, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMay, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJun,
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJul, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalAug, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalSep,
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalOct, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalNov, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalDec,
                Sum(CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJan + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalFeb + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMar +
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalApr + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMay + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJun +
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJul + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalAug + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalSep +
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalOct + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalNov + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalDec) AS Balance

        FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' INNER JOIN CostCodes ON CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.CostCode = CostCodes.CostCode 

        WHERE Costcodes.Costcode = @Nominal AND CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.FinPeriodNr =@CurrentPeriod

        GROUP BY CostCodes.CostCode, CostCodes.CostDescr, CostCodes.BankACType, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.FinPeriodNr, 
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJan, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalFeb, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMar,
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalApr, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMay, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJun,
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJul, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalAug, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalSep,
                CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalOct, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalNov, CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalDec;';

    SET @CurrentPeriod = @CurrentPeriod -1; --subtrace current period by 1
    END

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6),@CurrentPeriod INT, @ENDPeriod INT, @NOMINAL INT', @ORGCODE,@CurrentPeriod, @ENDPeriod, @NOMINAL; 

    SELECT * FROM #TempResults --to select the results of the code above

END
```

I'm still quite new to SQL so let me know what you think. I am calling this as a pass-through query from Access 2013.

Comment: First, put "SELECT * FROM #TempResults" outside the while.

Comment: why don't write a dynamic sql to insert data instead of select data? moreover, should `create table #TempResult` move outside the `while` loop? maybe after `drop table`

Comment: you might want to look into aliases - they let you give an alternative name to a table (or column) and would mean that you'd only need to concatenate the `@ORGCODE` into that string once. Also, don't name stored procedures starting with `sp_` - that's reserved for microsoft's System Procedures.

Comment: Not sure why i received a negative... at least explain why i got a negative so i understand...

Comment: Honestly the biggest issue you have here is a lack of normalization. Why do you need to store the data for each ORGCODE in its own table? I would include a column ORGCODE in the table. Then all you need to do is add a where clause and you wouldn't need the dynamic sql at all.

Comment: @SeanLange I think you are right but the system has already been developed this way which is why it is unfortunate that it cannot be changed. If it was all in one table it would be very simple to call up the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few things you need to check in the query:

1. Is  `@ENDPeriod` an input variable because you have harcoded it's
   values as  `SET @ENDPeriod = @CurrentPeriod-5` make sure it's the
   correct logic.
2. `CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.FinPeriodNr`  if this an integer value then you can compare it as `CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.FinPeriodNr BETWEEN @CurrentPeriod  AND @ENDPeriod` .

so re-write your sproc as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NominalRecord]
@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6),
@CurrentPeriod INT,
@ENDPeriod INT, 
@Nominal INT

AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @END INT;

SET @ENDPeriod = @CurrentPeriod-5 -- Please verify if this logic is actually required

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempResults')IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempResults

--WHILE (@CurrentPeriod<> @ENDPeriod)--loop through until endperiod is reached 
-- No need of while loop so commented    
    --BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE #TempResults
        (ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         CostCode INT,
         CostDescr VARCHAR(50),
         BankACType CHAR(2),
         FinPeriodNr SMALLINT,
         BalJan DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalFeb DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalMar DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalApr DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalMay DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalJun DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalJul DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalAug DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalSep DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalOct DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalNov DECIMAL(12, 2),
         BalDec DECIMAL(12, 2),
         Balance DECIMAL(12, 2))


    SET @SQL = N'
    SELECT CostCodes.CostCode,
    CostCodes.CostDescr,
    CostCodes.BankACType,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.FinPeriodNr, 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJan,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalFeb,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMar,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalApr,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMay,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJun,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJul,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalAug,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalSep,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalOct,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalNov,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalDec,
    Sum(CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJan
    + CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalFeb +
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMar +
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalApr +
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMay + 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJun +
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJul + 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalAug + 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalSep +
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalOct + 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalNov + 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalDec) AS Balance
    FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' 
    INNER JOIN CostCodes ON CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.CostCode 
    = CostCodes.CostCode 
    WHERE Costcodes.Costcode = @Nominal 
    AND CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.FinPeriodNr 
    BETWEEN @CurrentPeriod  AND @ENDPeriod
    GROUP BY CostCodes.CostCode,
    CostCodes.CostDescr, 
    CostCodes.BankACType, 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.FinPeriodNr, 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJan,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalFeb,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMar,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalApr,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalMay,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJun,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalJul,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalAug,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalSep,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalOct,
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalNov, 
    CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + '.BalDec;';

    --SET @CurrentPeriod = @CurrentPeriod -1; --subtrace current period by 1
    --END

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6),@CurrentPeriod INT, @ENDPeriod INT
    , @NOMINAL INT', @ORGCODE,@CurrentPeriod, @ENDPeriod, @NOMINAL; 

    SELECT * FROM #TempResults --to select the results of the code above

END
```

Comment: `FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' as ccb INNER JOIN` would let you just use `ccb` to reference the table everywhere else and avoid hundreds of repetitions of `+ @ORGCODE +`

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever..for pointing that out. I'll update back the query ..:)

Comment: @Deepshikha Your idea to use `BETWEEN` is the exact alternative I need which does the same thing but much less complicated. Thanks